# Condition check inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, conditional-statements

I want to filter data where `$data['stock'] != 0` from an json array. Can I put the condition check inside the **foreach** loop? Or, is there any better way to execute the same?

```
foreach($json['items'] as $data)
{
  if(!$data['stock'] == 0) {
    echo 'Success';
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with provided code?

Comment: _"Can I put the condition check inside the foreach loop?"_ - have you tried to do that and see what happens? There is no reason you wouldn't be able to do that. Though you might look into `array_filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want to achive. Your code is not wrong. You can also try playing with `array_filter()`.

```
$json = [
    "items" => [[
        "name" => "Widget",
        "stock" => 3
    ],[
        "name" => "Foo",
        "stock" => 0
    ],[
        "name" => "Bar",
        "stock" => 2
    ]]
];

$filtered_array = array_filter($json['items'], function($data){
 return $data['stock'];
 //Will get rid fo the Foo item because its stock is 0
});

var_dump($filtered_array);
// Will NOT contain the Foo item
```

Expected output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Widget"
    ["stock"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Bar"
    ["stock"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

This will filter your array to only contain those items that have a value in `$data['stock']`. You don't need to write `!= 0`, because in PHP, in this particular comparison context, `0` is translated as a boolean false.

[Quick demo](https://3v4l.org/AZ7L1)

Comment: Do I need to use the foreach loop too?

Comment: I added a demo so that it's a bit more clear what `array_filter()` does. I remember that I thought the method seemed really complicated at first, because you have an embedded function, but it's actually pretty straight forward. Not always a lot cleaner than using a `foreach()` loop, but it's a good one to have in your back pocket.

Comment: Or, with modern PHP: `array_filter($json["items"], fn ($item) => $item["stock"] > 0);`